# Splitting mail hosting between two mail servers?

Tags: email, email-server

I currently host a number of email accounts (on the same domain) via Google's Gmail service, managed through a paid Google Admin account. However, I need the ability to programmatically create new accounts for clients, and even if this were possible through Gmail, it would be prohibitively expensive.

This, in addition to the Gmail admin interface being generally terrible and immensely slow, I'd like to host my own mail server to give me more control over programmatically creating accounts and at a cheaper cost.

If I do this, would I need to transition all the Gmail accounts to my new mail server, or could I keep the legacy accounts on Gmail while hosting new accounts from my mail server? To make the transition smooth, I'd like to start only new accounts on my own mail server, and then move over the legacy accounts in phases. However, I realize the MX DNS record can only point to one server, so would that prevent me from using two servers to manage different accounts?

Comment: You need to look into using a shared SMTP namespace and whether the email server you're going to run supports that.

Answer (score 3):

Hosting a single e-mail domain on two (or more) servers is only possible when you have more or less full control over all mail servers  and they are not independent.

- As you already mention: **SMTP will route email to you based on the domain name and MX records** and the protocol does not provide more granular routing (i.e. a typical sending SMTP server won't route messages to `mailbox1@example.com` differently from messages to `mailbox2@example.com`  )

Since the sender can't make such a distinction, that means your own mail servers need both the ability and the configuration to that instead.

The default behaviour for most providers and mail servers is to  reject unknown e-mail addresses and to only accept messages  for known e-mail addresses for local delivery. (Although some will maybe accept all `@example.com`  e-mail addresses for local delivery in a catch-all account. )

What you would need from all servers that handle your @example.com e-mail domain is to lookup and distinguish first if indeed an somebody@example.com email address  exists and then make a routing decision if the message should be accepted for delivery to a local mailbox or sent on for further delivery to a remote mailbox stored on another server and if so: which one.

When not every mail server / service supports such email address based routing  you will see part of users will get delivery errors when they sent email to addresses not hosted on the same server / service that hosts their own mailbox.

As far as I know Gmail does not provide such support. Instead use a different domain, such as an associated `@example.net` or a subdomain such as an appropriate `@something.example.com` for the mailboxes that you don't want to store on Gmail.